# How to determine which element is selected

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<ul id="mainNav">
 <li id="item1"><a href="">item 1</a></li>
 <li id="item2"><a href="" class="selected">item 2</a></li>
 <li id="item3"><a href="">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to know how in jQuery to find the

ID based on which AHREF has class selected.
In this case return: "item2"

something like `$('#mainNav').find('.selected').parent().attr('id')`

Comment: That should work, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've suggested should work - but I'd simplify it to:

```
$('#mainNav .selected').parent().attr('id');
```

(Did you actually try your suggestion?)

Comment: I think it should be #mainNav a.selected

Comment: @TheApprentice: Yeah, otherwise anything with the "selected" class inside that div would be fair game.

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout:

```
var id = $("#mainNav li:has(a.selected)").attr("id");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uguhe3)

Comment: That returns the id of the link, not its parent.

Comment: @Alec: I realized as I clicked post and fixed it (even before your comment; overlap).